# How fast could a group of slaves in rebellion build a palisade fort with a gate and flanking towers/ whats in it?

Tags: warfare, medieval

I have a high fantasy story about a slave rebellion in an adjacent kingdom being backed by an empire who wishes to seize control over the kingdom. The deal is they'll help win the war and end the slave trade in the territory if they are given control over the kingdom.

I'm drawing on elements of the Roman slave rebellions in Sicily for some structure to the rebellion overall, but I am unsure about details of certain military actions. I have my slaves starting on a forest island off of the kingdom they were enslaved in. I figured if they were going to stay in this location and start formulating their rebellion they would need some sort of defensible position. I have them on a hilltop in a clearing they made after clearing the trees for lumber. I wanted to have palisade walls, a fortified gate and flanking towers, and possibly a secondary gate, because repetition was a big element of medieval defenses.

My question is first of all: Is this realistic, is this overkill/underkill? Then how long would this take to construct with approximately 100 people, half being in fine working condition? Then what would be inside of the palisade walls as far as living? Not everyone is a fighter, there are women and children and some elderly, and the weather and conditions are harsh in the area. Would it be entirely tent living and lean-tos worst case scenario, would their be some structures besides walls and towers?

My goal is to try and depict warfare accurately to the period so any advice here is appreciated! Just found this site, it's pretty neat and I figured I'd toss a question your way that I've been mulling on a bit.

Comment: What tools do they have available?  Foresters' tools (crosscut saws, axes, splitting mauls, mallets) make this a much easier task than, say, leather working tools (knives, small mallets, punches, burnishers).

Comment: Have you considered [motte and bailey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motte-and-bailey_castle), rather than palisade? It is less vulnerable to fire than a wooden palisade, and can be built quickly with farm tools. As long as the bailey holds you can use a mix of tents and the keep for housing, with the most vulnerable, such as mothers with very young children, getting space in the keep. If the bailey falls everyone has to crowd into the keep.

Comment: trapping pits are far easier to make and much faster do make as you could use hands to make a hole in the dirt.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that the Worldbuilding SE is dedicated to providing detailed answers to specific questions you have while developing your fictional world. To that end, we ask users to limit themselves to one question per post. Including multiple questions can leave answers unfocused or incomplete. Instead of multiple questions per post, consider asking multiple questions on a topic over time and linking them together, if doing so helps provide context. With multiple questions, this is likely to be closed as _needs focus_.

Comment: This depends on what were those slaves before being slaves, and on what do those slaves actually do for a living. A company of janissaries, who normally work as highly trained infantry, would build the fort quite quickly. A century of Roman legionaries enslaved by the Persians after the disastrous campaign of Crassus would also build it quickly. One hundred dancers and flute players would struggle to even understand what a palisade is supposed to be.

Comment: usually slave rebelion happen inside the town to stir chaos or overthrown their master to take over the town or fortification from inside, so far as i check first servile war also like that, why this slave in the outside of their owner town ? why not taken it from inside by surprise ? do the empire provide this slave with supply and tools or maybe profesional architect to help build this fortress?

Comment: You might consider paring down your question to focus on the idea you want help with.  By narrowing the scope to only essential information and asking a specific question, you may find you get a lot of very creative and insightful answers.  For instance, while the fact the are slaves is important to the story, is it important to the question?  I don’t believe so.   So you question might narrow down to How fast can N people build a log palisade using these tools.  You can ask multiple question — one per submission — to explore the space you are interested in developing.

Comment: Does the hilltop have a reliable, defensible water source? Allowing an average of half a gallon per person per day, more for physically active adults, less for children, you need 50 gallons a day.

Comment: One hundred folks of the era might mean closer to 25-or-so men in fine condition.  There will be children and oldsters and cripples, too. Also remember that free folks like to eat and care for their children, so hunting and gathering and child rearing will occupy some of those man-hours that you probably allotted to building. That force is too small to withstand any significant action - their best bet is to flee. [Chief Joseph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_Joseph)'s masterful management of just such a fleeing may be a good inspiration.

Answer (score 4):

A defensible position makes sense, and more importantly it makes sense to you as you visualize your story.

**Have your slaves take one over.**

Building a fortification like this is not trivial, as you realize.  This is not a pile of logs you are hiding behind.  But if the slaves have taken the island, you could have an existing fortification at a strategically important site (for example - overlooking the harbor) that they take with the island.  It would have stores of food and water, and the weapons of the time including weapons appropriate for repelling an attack by sea.  Although the slaves might not know how to operate these weapons.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on a million and one different things such as the motivation of the slaves, their health, the number of slaves, the size of the fortification, how well the slaves understand the process of building a fortification, the location of suitable wood, the nature of the ground for digging, the nature, quantity and quality for the tools used and many other things.

However to provide some sort of answer, in a best case scenario a fortification could be built in a matter of hours as was the case with [Roman marching camps](https://warfarehistorynetwork.com/2015/07/16/ancient-romes-military-marching-camps/). Allowing for some lack of expertise perhaps a day.

That said depending on the variables above it might have taken many days weeks or might not even have been possible. But given there are only 100 of them I suspect it would take many weeks.

Answer (score 2):

## Start gradually and improve it.

First, a ditch and earth berm. The time depends on the soil and the availability of tools like spades and picks, but 50 people should be able to do that in days.

Next, add stakes to the top. The Romans had prepared ones called [sudis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudis_(stake)), but sharp branches will do. Again, a day or days, depending on the availability of hatchets. The not-quite-healthy people might be able to help here.

Next, perhaps a watchtower. This requires axes, saws, etc., and suitable trees. Days?

Then the full-sized palisade. This will take quite some time, I guess.